# Magento 2 Admin panel links not working

Tags: magento2

[image]Menu and dropdown not opening when click on any link

Answer (score 1):

Kindly give permission to pub/static using below command

```
chmod -R 777 var pub/static
```

And then deploy static content using below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_CA

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Nothing happens. Issue is still there. I think problem is 'knockout' directory is not created under "pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_CA/Magento_Ui/js/lib/" . Have you any idea why this directory not created.?

Comment: Which is your store language?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: canadian dollar

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: "backend/en_CA/Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap.js 404 (Not Found)" only this error is coming and links are still not working

Comment: do you have any idea why bootstrap.js not created